# Tough Polynomial Roots and Inequality problem

Tags: inequality, polynomials, roots

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers. Let $r,$ $s,$ and $t$ be the roots of $f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx - 1,$ and then let $g(x) = x^3 + mx^2 + nx + p$ be a polynomial with roots $r^2,$ $s^2,$ and $t^2.$ If $g(-1) = -5,$ find the greatest possible value for $b.$

I got $rst=1$ and $(r^2+1)(s^2+1)(t^2+1)=5$ and you have to maximize $rs+st+tr$.

Comment: Do the roots have to be real?

Comment: apparently not!

Comment: If $f(x)=(x-r)(x-s)(x-t)$, then $-f(x)f(-x)=(x-r)(x+r)(x-s)(x+s)(x-t)(x+t)=(x^2-r^2)(x^2-s^2)(x^2-t^2)=g(x^2)$. Now, $-5=g(-1)=g(i^2)=-f(i)f(-i)=-|f(i)|^2=-((a+1)^2+(-1+b)^2)$. So, $(a,b)$ is a point on the circle $(a+1)^2+(b-1)^2=5$, with center $(-1,1)$ and radius $\sqrt{5}$. The largest $b$ coordinate is for $a=-1, b=1+\sqrt{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using the formulae for the roots is to let $y=x^2$.

Then $(y+b)x+ay-1=0$ and so $(y+b)^2y=(1-ay)^2$. Then $$g(y)=y^3+(2b-a^2)y^2+(b^2+2a)y-1.$$

substituting $g(-1)=-5$ gives $$-5=-1+(2b-a^2)-(b^2+2a)-1$$

Then $(a+1)^2+(b-1)^2=5$ and $b_{\text {max}}=1+\sqrt5$.